# node.js async.each callback, how do I know when it's done?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to wrap my head around Node.js and some async operations.  In the following code, I fetch some RSS feeds and store the articles found if I haven't stored them before.  The code works and stores new articles.  However, I'm not sure how to alter this so that I know when all the articles are done being parsed.  For example, the callback on each `async.eachLimit` gets called each time the limit is met (after 10 articles or 5 feeds).  So how do I know when they're done?

```
var FeedParser = require('feedparser');
var request = require('request');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var async = require('async');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host :  'localhost',
        user : 'someuser',
        password : 'somepass',
        database : 'somedb'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * FROM rssfeed', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if(err == null){
                async.eachLimit(rows, 5, parseFeed, function(err) {
                        if(! err) {
                                //horray
                        } else {
                                console.log(err);
                        }
                });
        }
});

function parseFeed(feed, callback) {
        var articles = [];
        request(feed.link)
        .pipe(new FeedParser())
        .on('error', function(error) {
                callback(error);
        })
        .on('meta', function(meta) {
        })
        .on('readable', function() {
                var stream = this, item;
                item = stream.read();
                if(item != null) {
                        item.rssfeed_id = feed.id;
                        articles.push(item);
                }
        })
        .on('finish', function() {
                async.eachLimit(articles, 10, parseArticle, function(err) {
                        if(! err) {
                                console.log('article each callback');
                        } else {
                                callback(error);
                        }
                });
        });
        callback();
}
function parseArticle(item, callback) {
        if(item.hasOwnProperty('rssfeed_id') && item.hasOwnProperty('guid') && item.hasOwnProperty('link') && item.hasOwnProperty('title')){
                connection.query('SELECT * FROM rssarticle WHERE rssfeed_id = ? AND guid = ?', [item.rssfeed_id, item.guid], function(err, rows, fields) {
                        if(rows.length == 0){
                                connection.query('INSERT INTO rssarticle SET ?', {
                                        rssfeed_id: item.rssfeed_id,
                                        link: item.link,
                                        title: item.title,
                                        description: item.description,
                                        publish_date: item.pubDate,
                                        guid: item.guid
                                }, function(err, result){
                                        if(err != null){
                                                console.log(err);
                                        }
                                });
                        }
                });
        }
        callback();
}
```

Comment: Uhm, the callback is called after all the async operations in the iteration has completed, are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For one, you're preemptively calling your callbacks way too early.

```
function parseFeed(feed, callback) {
  request
    .streamStuff()
    .streamStuff()
    .streamStuff();

  callback();
}
```

You shouldn't be calling `callback` before you're done. Otherwise your "finished" method will be called but your async code will actually still be running.

So instead of doing:

```
.on('finish', function() {
    async.eachLimit(articles, 10, parseArticle, function(err) {
        if(! err) {
            console.log('article each callback');
        } else {
            callback(error);
        }
    });
});
callback();
```

Just do

```
.on('finish', function() {
    async.eachLimit(articles, 10, parseArticle, function(err) {
        if(! err) {
            // assuming this is a stub and really ends up doing `callback();`
            console.log('article each callback');
        } else {
            callback(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: AHA!  There we go.  I moved the callback into the `eachLimit` pertaining to articles.  Fixed everything.  Thanks!

Comment: It's all a matter of keeping things simple, in the future work with more named function (as opposed to anonymous ones), and it'll be easier for you to see where the async flow leads.

Comment: Also, giving callbacks more appropriate names is really useful, I like to use `next` and `done` to differentiate them, for example.

Comment: +1 - Well spotted on the callbacks being called before the async functions where done.